# How can I align text next to image with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html

I created a box in that box is one image and i want text to be next to image in left side of the box in right side of the box i want to have some text, but it doesn't work.

On left side everything seems ok, but text that suppose to be on right side goes under div with image and text.

Basically it has to look like this

```
[img - text [gap] text]
```

But looks like

```
[img text
          [gap] text ]
```

I tried at first doing it with floats but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="card row mt-5">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
      <img src="avatar.jpg" alt="duck">
      <p class="text">Vardenis Pavardenis<br>
        Kebulo Meistras<br>
        Petro servisas<br>
        Kauans<br></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <p>asdasdasd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What size screen are you on? Your columns stack until the large breakpoint when using `col-lg-*`.

Comment: So simply changing to `col-*` fixes the problem. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u5erxfht/) what you're after? Note that I've moved the row to a separate element. It often complicates things to mix Bootstrap components on a single element.

Comment: BTW, you probably don't need those interior flex containers: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u5erxfht/6/

Comment: no col-x doesnt fix the problem i tried i thought maybe its the problem so i tried col-lg x)

Comment: Found problem it was because in css i used earlier display:block; and forgot to delete :)